# unable to use getCreatedAt() with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

So I have been developing an android application that has actually gone quite well up until now. I am simply trying to get the creation date of an object stored in Parse. Parse recommends that you use the ParseObject.getCreatedAt() - makes sense. For some reason every time I try to get the creation date my values are returning null. The creation dates are most definitely there in the table of data. I am wondering if this issue is being caused by User permissions at runtime? If anyone knows how I can solve this problem please let me know.

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Post>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(Post object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.urgent_item, null);
            }
            ParseImageView postImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Image");
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            if (imageFile != null) {
                postImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
                tv.setText(object.getUpdatedAt().toString());
                postImage.loadInBackground();
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
```

I am getting a null value when setting the textView text. Parse automatically stores the creation date, and like I said, I can see all of the dates in the table. Part of me thinks that the user permissions are blocking this value from being accessed. My user settings are like this

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
defaultACL.setReadAccess(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(),true);
defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
// Optionally enable public read access.
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

Something else I tried was to store the date and time texts that I need as String keys but I really dont want to have to do that as a workaround because I should have to technically. Again, if anyone has any insight on this specific variables in parse database please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: sorry the code above uses the getUpdateAt(), I was testing this method because getCreatedAt() was not working. Both have values in the table and both do not work :(

Comment: can you please try Lod.d("DEBUG", "value-->"+object.getUpdatedAt().toString()) before the setText on the textfield and check what it returns?

Comment: Interesting, thank you for showing me how to debug like this. I got the following from executing this.                                                                      03-01 14:28:01.194  25658-25658/com.parse.starter D/DEBUG﹕ value-->Sun Mar 01 12:35:22 EST 2015

Comment: And your TextView shows the string "null" after this runs?  Any chance it's being updated somewhere else too?